# Memory Router doesn't use the browsers back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Using react-router 4.2.2

Following the documentation at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md (Which is lacking a good example)

I have the following

```
<MemoryRouter
   initialEntries={[
     '/one',
     '/two'
 ]}>
     <div>
       <Route path="/one" component={FirstPage} />
       <Route path="/two" component={SecondPage} />
     </div>
 </MemoryRouter>
```

I can then use the following to easily navigate pages:

```
this.props.history.push('/two');
```

This works as intended. However, when I hit my browsers back button it does not take me back to the previous route.

While I could easily have navigation buttons on screen, I would love for the browsers back button to work as well. Can memory router do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Memory Router specifically doesn't write anything to the browser's history, and as such you would need to handle this manually. One thing you can do is add an event listener:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = this.handleNavigation.bind(this);
}

handleNavigation(event) {
    if (//event is going back) {
        this.props.history.go(-1); // Or .goBack() if available, or whatever the equivalent is. Possibly will need to keep track of currentLocation in relation to an array and navigate that way.
    } else if (//If event is going forward) {
        this.props.history.go(1); // Or .goForward() if available
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the only way to be able to use the browsers back button to manipulate the url with react-router?

Comment: I've never worked with MemoryRouter myself, so don't take my word for it, but I have worked with BrowserHistory quite a bit, and it definitely handles navigation the way you intend. If you don't have a compelling reason to use MemoryRouter, I would definitely look into BrowserHistory.

Comment: I've also used BrowerHistory quite a bit, but my use case is I don't want to manipulate the actual url

Comment: @Galupuf did this solution work for you?  I have a similar use case where I can't actually change the URL

Comment: I did not, I had to go a different route. To my understanding memory router can't do this. I'm assuming it's because memory router is not for browsers. It's only "Useful in tests and non-browser environments like React Native" - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/MemoryRouter.md

Comment: @Galupuf, what method did you use if you don't mind explaining? I can't modify the URL either but would like to use the router.

Comment: the if and elseif conditions comments in the provided code actually break the code syntax, and it would be very insightful to know how this logic should be written in the context of a React component and using a MemoryRouter